# Sending Primary Key of object via Ajax

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-templates

How to send primary key(pk) of the *SELECTED* object via AJAX. I tried {{pk}}, but unsuccessful. I am getting an error "Uncaught error" unexpected token}

```
{% extends 'homepage.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block teacher_diary %}
<script language="JavaScript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#grade_list').change(function(){
        var element = document.getElementById("grade_list");
        var value = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
    $.ajax({
        url: "get_subject/",
        type: "get",
        data: {
            'grade_id': value.{{ pk }}
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });

})});
</script>
<select id="grade_list">
    {% for grade in grades %}
        <option >{{ grade }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable identified as `value` does not have any attribute called {{pk}}. The use of double curly braces is reserved for server side processing of the template before the HTML is sent to the client. There is no notion of Django objects on the client side. Hopefully this makes intuitive sense.

As far as the solution, here is something that I might do. First, give each option a custom attribute `data-pk` that stores the pk from the server side.

```
<select id="grade_list">
    {% for grade in grades %}
        <option data-pk={{grade.pk}} >{{ grade }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Then, access the pk as such using JavaScript (If you choose to use JQuery, there are easier ways).

```
    var element = document.getElementById("grade_list");
    var value = element.options[element.selectedIndex];
    $.ajax({
        url: "get_subject/",
        type: "get",
        data: {
            'grade_id': value.getAttribute("data-pk");
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
```